# How to hide fields when uploading documents in the document library upload.asmx

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, document-upload

I'm using Sharepoint 2013

I have a library of documents in which I upload different documents, I would like that when I upload these documents, the fields that I have there in the form do not appear.

[image]

I don't want the last two fields to show up when uploading new documents, I'm only interested in hiding them in the **upload.asmx** form.

Try to do what it says in this [documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/remove-columns-from-upload-aspx-page-in-document-library/m-p/174781) but this hides the fields from me in all forms including DispForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx

**UPDATE:**

I also made use of the sputility library but I don't get any result

I followed the documentation found in this [git](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility)

And add the following script in a new Web Part:

```
<script src="/site/Test/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="/site/Test/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
   SPUtility.GetSPField('Aprobador').MakeReadOnly();
   SPUtility.GetSPField('Aprobador SGC').MakeReadOnly();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provide actually is a EditForm.aspx. If you want to hide a field in the EditForm.aspx, you could run below PowerShell as administrator.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Get the Web
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "site collection URL"
#Get the List
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["library name"]
#Get the Field
$SPField = $SPList.Fields["column name"]
 
$SPField.ShowInEditForm = $false

$SPField.Update()
$SPWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: I have to run power shell from the server or I can do it from my client machine ?

Comment: You could run it both in the your SharePoint server or your client machine.